# What does "p-p" mean in a spec sheet?

Tags: schematics, specifications

I've been searching for what these unit abbreviations mean, and can't seem to find anything. I'm hoping for some help. I'm looking at a spec sheet for a Vacuum fluorescent display

For the Grid and Anode voltage it lists the units as Vp-p and for the amperage are using unit mAp-p.

Most of the other units that aren't "p-p" are Vac or mAac which I assume mean "Volts, alternating current. milliamps, alternating current."

This leads me to believe that "p-p" means some sort of direct current, but there are other specs that specifically have "Vdc", so it must not be that.

Could someone tell me what p-p means in a spec sheet? I can't seem to find a reference anywhere (granted it is a lexically difficult term to search for).

spec sheet the question comes from (if that helps): 
http://www.newhavendisplay.com/specs/D0106LT-33-0604N.pdf

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

p-p means peak to peak. If not mentioned otherwise, V ac or amps ac are taken to be RMS (root mean square) values.

Comment: thanks Martin, just to clarify (I'm new to using AC, I'm a hobbyist who mostly uses DC currents) RMS would be the average value (of the up and down of the wave). Peak would be the max value of either the top or bottom of the wave. And peek to peak would mean the TOTAL level from top to bottom?

Comment: @dprogramz  Suggest you google RMS, since your definition is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The abbreviation 'p-p' is used to mean 'peak-to-peak'.

Peak amplitude (V<sub>pk</sub>) is from the midpoint to the peak of the wave, peak-to-peak (V<sub>p-p</sub>) is from the peak to the bottom of the trough. See the following image. 
[image]

<sup>(source: http://azimadli.com/vibman/vibrationamplitudemeasurement.htm)</sup>

Comment: ah that makes sense, thank you. I'm much better dealing with DC current, so I'm trying to get a better grasp on AC. So in terms of mAp-p, that means when it says the maximum amps are 10 its 5 amps up, 5 amps down in the sinusoidal wave

Comment: mA means milliamps, \$ milli =10^{-3}\$, e.g.  \$5\: mA\:=\:0.005\: A\$

Answer (score 1):

It means peak-to-peak voltages or currents. Those displays are multiplexed so the grids and anodes are fed with square waveforms so their peak voltage or current is more important than for example the heater voltage/current which is given just in RMS voltages.